# Integrating eclipse with db2

Tags: eclipse, db2

I was doing a project related to the IBM competition and need to create a web application. I have done a web application before by connecting netbeans and mysql. But, now am facing problem right from installation.
Is there any workbench(like something for mysql)  for db2 . If so can anyone give a link. Also, I need to make jdbc connections. So, is there any other software I need to install. 
Kindly explain to me in detail as I'm not pretty sure about this.

Comment: Why do you need anything other than a DB2 JDBC driver JAR?

Comment: @duffymo , Thanks . So, I just need to install the driver is it. How do I view the data. Like in mysql workbench , I can see all data being added. And where do I create my tables.

Comment: Create and view data in a DB2 admin client or something like SQL Squirrel: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a [DB2 JDBC JAR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866).  Pick the appropriate one for your version and add it to your CLASSPATH.

You should use either a DB2 admin client to create tables and view data or something like [SQL Squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks. So , I install the DB2 JDBC JAR to connect . I have downloaded DB-2 express C. So, will there be any help from that software. If so could answer the above query correspondingly ?

Comment: Help with what?  I don't understand what else you need.  What does NetBeans have to do with anything?  It's just an IDE, not a web application platform.  What do you intend to deploy to - WebSphere?

Comment: Deploy it on Apache Tomcat. What I meant was, if I have DB2 Express C installed , how could I proceed with my project.

Comment: OK.  Start up the DB2 client, issue the appropriate SQL commands to CREATE TABLE, INSERT the data, write the Java to access and modify it, write the Java front end to present it to the user.  Enough?